# Flash Privacy Popup Dialog is missing "Remember" checkbox

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

I am trying to get the Privacy Settings Tab to show in our flash/flex4 video chat application we are building.  I have 2 systems with latest Flash installed (currently 11.1.102.62).  However, the player always shows [this](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help05.html) (privacy popup question) instead of [this](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help09.html) (privacy settings tab) when loading the app.  The reason i want the settings tab to show is because i need the end user to easily check the "remember" box.

I have tried to call `Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);` before as well as after the getCamera/getMicrophone calls but all that happens is we get 2 popups instead of 1.  and still no "remember" option.  Actually it doesnt show the privacy tab at all!

Searched tons of forums but have come up empty.  I have also searched the adobe docs but all I find is a paragraph stating  "*if your computer or device doesn't support audio or video recording using Flash Player, you don't need to allow or deny access, and this panel doesn't appear*".  Which is hardly true since one of the systems we are testing with is a new Macbook Air running latest OSX.

Does anyone have any insight into why this might be happening and how to display the "**Privacy  Settings**" and not the "**Privacy pop-up question**"?

Comment: If you manually invoke the dialog by right clicking and going to settings, is there a "remember" checkbox?

Comment: Does the problem happen in all browsers? Note that Chrome (Pepper Flash) and IE (ActiveX Flash) have their own Flash plugins, so these may behave differently. I've seen this happen when "private" or "incognito" browsing is enabled or any situation where the browser *thinks* it can't save the settings (likely a Flash or browser bug in this case).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in the current Flash player version. The popup freezes sometimes too.

I've educated users of my application to [pre-set their settings](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/ru/flashplayer/help/settings_manager06.html).