# allow deny remember flash security panel

Tags: flash, security, webcam

Why is it that some flash sites have the option to 
'allow' 'deny' and 'remember' under the privacy options for camera/mic
and some flash sites have only 'allow' and 'deny'

[image: flash security]

Comment: It appears to be a bug. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541251/flash-privacy-popup-dialog-is-missing-remember-checkbox)

Answer (score 8):

It may be buggy :) but these are two separate dialog boxes.

The first image is the "privacy" panel, it has the option to remember the setting. It is specifically invoked (as shown in the link in @lazfish's comment) by calling `Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);`.

The second dialog is a default dialog shown by Flash player when an app tries to use the camera/microphone.

**Edit:** just to be clear... "default" is not referring to `SecurityPanel.DEFAULT` ... I am referring to a generic dialog that Flash Player shows, by default, if the user has not yet granted access to camera/microphone.

More user friendly apps will make the privacy panel appear, so the user can grant access and click "remember". Other apps just try to access your camera, and so if the user has not previously allowed it, Flash Player automatically shows the "default" dialog.

Another reason you will see the "default" dialog is when using "incognito" browsing (in Chrome for example). In this case the browser will never show the "privacy" dialog and only shows the "default" dialog.

Comment: Thanks for that response.. I am calling security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);. when the user clicks a button ,, from what I can recall the same code compiled with AS2 brings up the 'allow','deny','remember' dialog and with AS3 just the allow,deny..

Comment: Have you tried different browsers? We had an issue where Chrome was **not** in incognito mode, but one day it started showing the dialog w/out the "remember" option (as if it were incognito). The user tried a different browser and saw the correct dialog.

Comment: "hen using "incognito" browsing (in Chrome for example)",,  what is the alternative to the default dialog box, and what is incognito mode ? - something like a safe-mode ?

Comment: It's [private browsing](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95464&p=cpn_incognito) - amongst other things, cookies (and Flash settings) aren't saved, so Flash Player does not show the privacy panel. The alternative to the default dialog **is** the privacy panel (the one w/the remember setting). It's not clear why it doesn't appear if you're specifically opening it with `Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);`