# AS3 Microphone Privacy Settings Only Shows 3 Tabs

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, firefox, privacy

So i've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out, and it's about time I ask for help. I have a flash audio recorder that is displaying a popup to the user asking them to allow microphone access using:

**AS3 --**

Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);

Now, on chrome it works perfect! Everything shows up correctly and looks like this:

http://postimage.org/image/6e6ldfmpj/

Great. Now the issue is, on Firefox (and I believe IE9) it looks like:

http://postimage.org/image/mqp1kmcjj/

Notice how there are only 3 tabs in the second one (Firefox). Well, the second tab over is Privacy and allows you to "allow" or "deny" our website from accessing your mic. So it's a bit of an issue that that tab is not even visible... Any thoughts on that? I can't seem to find anywhere where anyone has had that same flash dialog box pop up with only 3 tabs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ugh, I wish I'd found the solution and I'd help! I've tested most things...I'm still working on it though and I'll let you know if I come up with anything.

Comment: I'll say that the only fix I've found mentioned online is to completely reinstall Firefox (deleting all configurations and preferences). Not exactly something you want to have to tell everyone who has this problem.

Comment: The key is, this is not the same on everyone's Firefox. For example, my boss has this issue but my version of Firefox shows all the tabs.

Comment: I've seen those tabs go missing when the user has enabled "private" or "incognito" browsing. Chrome has such a feature, but I'm not aware of such an option in Firefox or IE. When you're using "private browsing" the browser doesn't save any cookies, and Flash won't show that "remember" option.

Comment: Hmm, so maybe it has something to do with cookies not being enabled?

Comment: No, I think even with cookies disabled the privacy panel should still be available, it just won't have the "Remember" checkbox... I mean, technically all of the settings would be remembered by cookies, so if this was the case *all* of the panels would be missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Allow][Deny] dialog:

[image: Allow/Deny Flash Player dialog]

It appears whenever you access microphone/camera by attaching them to NetStream.

Related question on stackoverflow:
[allow deny remember flash security panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318279/allow-deny-remember-flash-security-panel)

Answer (score 1):

As Sunil D. mentioned above, Firefox will not show some tabs in private/incognito mode. The problem is user can turn it on not only by opening new private window, but also by changing some regular Firefox preferences. Go to Firefox options, select "Privacy" tab and search for "History" group. There you will see a dropdown with "Firefox will:" label. There you can select "Never remember history" item and browser will show you a small tip:

> Firefox will use the same settings as private browsing, and will not remember any history as you browse the Web.

Then your browser will be restarted. Further research revealed that Firefox really turns private mode on after such manipulations. Sunil D. and Jordan Reiter were both right - the problem can happen with users in private mode and problem can be solved by reinstalling Firefox with all it's configurations (including that history setting). Of course, it's much easier to ask users to change that setting. Also private mode detection with JavaScript can help to inform user about this expected problem.